# Remove sundays from array of dates but adjust for removal of sundays

Tags: ruby

Given an array of consecutive dates `dates = (1..15).map { |num| Date.today + num }` how do I remove the sunday's but retain the original array length by adding an additional day to the end for every removed sunday?

This is my attempt, which results in a "stack level too deep" exception.

```
def remove_sundays(dates)
  working_dates = dates.reject(&:sunday?)
  size_diff  = dates.size - working_dates.size
  unless size_diff.zero?
    last_day = working_dates.last
    working_dates = working_dates + ((1..size_diff).map { |num| last_day + num })
    remove_sundays(working_dates)
  else
    working_dates
  end
end
```

Comment: Date#sunday? is in Rails 1.9.3, so if it was once a rails extension, it has since been ported to base Ruby.

Comment: Will the dates always be consecutive?

Comment: @WayneConrad Good to know, question update to remove Rails reference. Yes they will be consecutive days, I have also updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: In that case, it might be simpler to create the list without any Sundays in it.  Please see the section "alternative" that I've just added to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is the recursion, here:

```
remove_sundays(working_dates)
```

Consider what happens if the last working date is a Sunday.  The function will remove that date, then see that it needs to add a date, then it adds a date, which will be Sunday.  This causes the recursion to never terminate.

## solution

But this can be done without recursion:

```
def remove_sundays(dates)
  non_sundays = dates.reject(&:sunday?)
  sunday_count = dates.size - non_sundays.size
  date = dates.last + 1
  sunday_count.times.map do  
    date += 1 if date.sunday?
    non_sundays << date
    date += 1
  end
  non_sundays
end
```

## explanation

These two lines are the the same as yours, but with different variable names:

```
  non_sundays = dates.reject(&:sunday?)
  sunday_count = dates.size - non_sundays.size
```

The temporary variable *date* will hold the next day to be added.

```
  date = dates.last + 1
```

Now add dates to the end, one for each Sunday we removed, *but* don't add any Sundays.

```
  sunday_count.times.map do  
    date += 1 if date.sunday?
    non_sundays << date
    date += 1
  end
```

and, finally, return the result

```
  non_sundays
```

## alternative

If the dates will always be consecutive, as the OP states, then it might be simpler to simply build the list without any Sundays (rather than building a list with Sundays, and then remove them).

```
def dates_without_sunday(date, count)
  date -= 1
  count.times.map do
    date += 1
    date += 1 if date.sunday?
    date
  end
end

dates = dates_without_sunday(Date.new(2014, 1, 16), 7)
p dates.map(&:wday)
# => [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I adapted the alternative solution. See my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hard one.

```
def remove_sundays(dates)
 dates.each.with_index do |d, i|
   if d.sunday?
     dates[i..-1] = dates[i..-1].map(&:next_day)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: Shiny.  This solution is O(n^2) whereas mine is O(n), but this is beautiful.  Except for very large lists, I prefer this solution.

Comment: Ivan, The new solution is O(n), but not beautiful at all.  It also assumes that the dates are consecutive.  The OP's example input data is consecutive, but we don't know that it will always be so.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted Wayne's answer:

```
def remove_sundays(dates)
  date = dates.first - 1
  dates.size.times.map do
    date += 1
    date += 1 if date.sunday?
    date
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach, for your consideration.

I've generalised it to accept an array of wday's, so you can more easily exclude any combinations of days of the week. A "1" in a location indicates that the wday should be included in the output list.

```
def day_list(start_date = Date.today, day_count = 1, include_days = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
  date_list    = Array.new
  date         = start_date 
  wday_pattern = include_days
  while date_list.size < day_count
    date_list << date if wday_pattern[date.wday] == 1
    date = date+1
  end
  date_list
end
```

In action ...

```
2.0.0dev :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.0.0dev :002 > 
2.0.0dev :003 >   def day_list(start_date = Date.today, day_count = 1, include_days = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
2.0.0dev :004?>     date_list    = Array.new
2.0.0dev :005?>     date         = start_date 
2.0.0dev :006?>     wday_pattern = include_days
2.0.0dev :007?>     while date_list.size < day_count
2.0.0dev :008?>         date_list << date if wday_pattern[date.wday] == 1
2.0.0dev :009?>         date = date+1
2.0.0dev :010?>       end
2.0.0dev :011?>     date_list
2.0.0dev :012?>   end
 => nil 
2.0.0dev :013 > day_list
 => [#<Date: 2014-01-16 ((2456674j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
2.0.0dev :014 > day_list(Date.today,15,[1,1,1,1,1,1,0])
 => [#<Date: 2014-01-16 ((2456674j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-17 ((2456675j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-19 ((2456677j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-20 ((2456678j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-21 ((2456679j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-22 ((2456680j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-23 ((2456681j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-24 ((2456682j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-26 ((2456684j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-27 ((2456685j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-28 ((2456686j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-29 ((2456687j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-30 ((2456688j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-31 ((2456689j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-02-02 ((2456691j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
2.0.0dev :015 > day_list(Date.today,8,[1,0,1,0,1,1,0])
 => [#<Date: 2014-01-16 ((2456674j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-17 ((2456675j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-19 ((2456677j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-21 ((2456679j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-23 ((2456681j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-24 ((2456682j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-26 ((2456684j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2014-01-28 ((2456686j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
2.0.0dev :016 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
require `date`
dates = (1..15).map { |num| Date.today + num }
  #            dates.day=>[17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

new_dates = dates.reject(&:sunday?)
  # new_dates.map(&:day)=>[17,18,   20,21,22,23,24,25,   27,28,29,30,31]

next_date = new_dates.last + 1
loop do
  new_dates << next_date unless next_date.sunday?
  next_date += 1
  break if new_dates.size == dates.size
end
  # new_dates.map(&:day)=>[17,18,   20,21,22,23,24,25,   27,28,29,30,31,1,  3]
```

As @Wayne has observed, it's easier to generate the Sunday-less array directly.  This can be done very easily: construct an array containing a bunch of consecutive dates, strip out the Sundays and slice off the required number of days.  To determine the minimum size of "bunch", observe that the next `count` days can contain at most `(count + 6)/7` Sundays.  Hence,

```
  today = Date.today
  count = 15

  new_dates = 1.upto(count+(count+6)/7).map \
    { |i| today+i }.reject(&:sunday?).first(count)
  # new_dates.map(&:day)=>[17,18,   20,21,22,23,24,25,  27,28,29,30,31,1,   3]
```